# Ruby 1.9.3 -> 2.0 alias_method and extend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade a Ruby 1.9.3 app to 2.0, and everything seems to have gone smoothly except for one hiccup. I wrote a module which I include in my models to override activerecord destroy. It aliases the existing `destroy` method to `destroy!` and then overrides `destroy` to change a `deleted_at` timestamp on the record. Only when I upgrade to ruby 2.0 `destroy!` no longer destroys the record, but behaves just like my new override method. Any idea why this would be? The more relevant section of code is below. Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mockdeep/7574103).

```
  def self.included(base)                                                          
    base.class_eval do                                                             
      alias_method :destroy!, :destroy                                             
      alias_method :delete!, :delete                                               
      default_scope -> { where(:deleted_at => nil) }                               
    end                                                                            

    base.send :extend, ClassMethods                                                
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods                                            
  end
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to solve your initial problem. Overriding the core methods (like destroy or delete) will cause you and any other developer that works on this a lot of headache... I'd suggest a method named something like `update_deleted_at` (which is actually what you're doing) instead of overriding the `destroy` method. Just because you **can** override something with ruby, it doesn't mean you should...

Comment: I'd agree with @tyler, I can't imagine a compelling reason where this would save more time than the time that would be lost maintaining it.

Comment: While I can appreciate the sentiment, my goal wasn't to save time, but to make it difficult to accidentally delete data and to make it transparent to outside users. I'm sure to continue revising my solution, but if nothing else than for curiosity's sake, do you have an answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you alias a method that is not directly defined in the current class, then `alias` looks for the method in the nearest ancestor of the class in which it was executed.

When you include `Trashable::InstanceMethods` into one of your models, it gets inserted at the front of that model's ancestor chain. Hence, calling `destroy!` in that model triggers the `destroy` method on `Trashable::InstanceMethods`.

If you move `def destroy` from `InstanceMethods` to `base.class_eval`, then it would be defined in the including model directly, and the nearest ancestor of that model that contains 'destroy' would be the relevant module in ActiveRecord. Therefore calling `destroy!` would trigger an SQL `DELETE` as expected.

See `class.ancestors` to further explore this behavior.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. Thanks! Strange that it behaves differently in 1.9.3 from 2.0.0. The ancestry looks the same in both. Something like: `[..., Trashable::InstanceMethods, Trashable, ..., ActiveRecord::Base, ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia).  It's a Rails 3/4 compatible implementation of soft deletes that does just what you're after.  If all you want to do is provide a soft-delete then I'd use the gem and be done with it.  If you *want* to implement soft deletes yourself, then the implementation can give you some insights into how it's been done before.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at paranoia but decided that it was too heavyweight for us. I want the flexibility to be able to change the behavior down the road as we figure out how we want it to work. I have looked over the implementation some for inspiration, though. I'll take another look.

Comment: If you're early on in a project then I'd opt for the simplest solution to the problem, particularly if it's implementation coincides with your plans.  From personal experience I can tell you that the "...but we might like it to do..." approach to development will get you into a lot of unsupportable code.  Wait for that feature to _demand_ it's inclusion and then refactor (which should be as simple as switching out a community gem for your own in this case).  That said, Rails' added the alias_method_chain macro for just this purpose.

Comment: In this case the simplest solution to the problem was to build it myself instead of using a heavyweight solution. Knowing that we don't have a firm understanding of how we want it to work in the future I opted to build it myself so that it would be easily extensible instead of having to hack around a gem. The code isn't very complex and it's well tested, so maintenance shouldn't be a lot of trouble. I've been bitten more than once by gems that do more than I need or interact in strange ways with others.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 2.0 they introduced the concept of prepending modules, so you can insert behaviour between your model and ActiveRecord::Base. I would suggest moving your code into a module and instead of including that model, you can prepend it. Saves from aliasing methods around.

Here are some articles related to the new prepend functionality:

https://gist.github.com/mattetti/5104790

http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/11/05/3-killer-features-that-are-coming-on-ruby-2-0.html

http://dev.af83.com/2012/10/19/ruby-2-0-module-prepend.html

Comment: As with the above answer, what you are implementing is more of a safe delete... ie. setting a record as deleted without actually deleting it. I generally use a state machine for this type of work (usually the `state_machine` gem: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), since it makes it easy to customize the behaviour of what you want to happen and provides all sorts of helpful methods.  Heres a good article on it: https://mojolingo.com/blog/2013/state-machines/

Comment: Implementing a state machine doesn't really help at all here. There are no complicated state transitions to manage. It's either deleted or it's not. I want to override the existing delete functionality, and to have the deleted records not show up anywhere unless I specifically query for them.

Comment: check out @AndyV anser. `acts_as_paranoid` is exactly what you're looking for... but a state machine doesn't have to be complicated and is generally better than managing boolean flags... even if you only have two states... but I agree with you, for only a paranoid delete sort of functionality, a state machine is overkill.  Go with `paranoia`.

Comment: I mentioned above that I already looked into that gem and found it to be overkill as well, though I have been using it as reference. The way they handle it is just to completely rewrite the original `destroy` method as well, rather than aliasing it. Their `destroy!` method conflicts in functionality with that provided by rails.